# Blender box selection adding suddenly fails

Tags: selection-tools

I'm trying to box-select multiple vertices, at first, it always works fine

1. I press <kbd>B</kbd> , then I select some vertices.
2. I press <kbd>B</kbd> again, and I select some more.
3. Then again.
4. Then again.
5. Then I press <kbd>B</kbd>, and as soon as I hold down the mouse button, the
   previous selection goes away.

It's always like that, it works some time, then suddenly the previous selection goes away, I have no idea what is happening here. Can anybody explain this?

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/cyx6Et8UI-c)

Edit: What I do notice is that once the bug happens, a single vertex is selected... which I have not done, so maybe it's a real bug?

Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/k4uqU-BqbxA) that shows how suddenly a single vertex is selected.

I'm using this Blender version: 2.79b, f4dc9f9d68b, 2018-03-22 14:10

Comment: So... how about we start with the Blender version you're talking about? Just an idea...

Comment: You mean I should state my Blender version? I have added it to my posting.